# PHP - Best way to concatenate two or more strings with similar substring

Tags: php, string, concatenation

i have array of string:

```
array('name is required','email is required','email is not valid','ip is not valid')
```

what is the best way to concatenate these strings into single string like this:

```
name, email is required. email, ip is not valid
```

Answer (score 2):

The function you are looking for is called implode().

```
$str = implode(',',$array);
```

Although I didn't get the question at first, you better stick to this one. Lexical parser is not what you need for simple error messages output.

Comment: It won't give the punctuation that the question asked for in his output string, but this is the right way. +1

Comment: Ah, I see now. He's calling it "concatenate".

Comment: I meant that he has a comma after name, thena  full stop after the second array element, then another comma and so on :)

Comment: i think implode isn't the solution.it just make a string from array items, not produce string as i expected

Answer (score -1):

here i give a advise

```
<?php
define("DELIMITER", "is");
$a = array('name is required','email is required','email is not valid','ip is not valid');
foreach($a as $k=>$v){
    $arr = explode(DELIMITER, $v, 2);
    $subject = trim($arr[0]);
    $description = trim($arr[1]);
    $res[$description][] = $subject;
}
foreach($res as $k=>$v){
    echo implode(",", $v)." ".DELIMITER." ".$k.". ";
}
echo "\n";
```

Comment: this is quite limited version, tied to offered example only, and unusable in all other cases

Comment: if you get a model like “xx {delimiter} xx”, this will be working well.if not, i'm sorry